# Hibernate - How can I force it programmatically to return Long instead of BigInteger?

Tags: java, hibernate, casting

I have this method in one of the DAOs of my project.
The underlying RDBMS is MS SQL Server.
The `se_subaccountid` is defined as `bigint` on the DB level.

Hibernate returns to me `List<BigInteger>`.
I don't want to have BigInteger objects but Long objects.
How I can tell Hibernate to return to me a `List<Long>`?
I want to do it programmatically here in this method,
as I don't want my changes to have global impact.
Is that possible and how?

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public List<Long> getAllCheckSubAccounts() {
    Object res = getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback() {
        public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

            String sql =
                    "select " + 
                    " " + 
                    "distinct sa.se_subaccountid as cid " + 
                    " " + 
                    "from  " + 
                    "subaccount sa  " + 
                    "inner join account a on sa.accountid = a.accountid " + 
                    "inner join product m on sa.mb_id = m.mb_id  " + 
                    "where " + 
                    "(a.se_id = 2) " + 
                    "and " + 
                    "(sa.se_subaccountid is not null)  " + 
                    "and " + 
                    "(m.mb_status not in (128, 512)) " + 
                    "order by  " + 
                    "sa.se_subaccountid asc ";

            SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
            return query.list();
        }
    });

    return ((List<Long>) res);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM CATS")
    .addScalar("cid", StandardBasicTypes.LONG)
```

Similar thread here:
[How to specify data type when using native SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860347/how-to-specify-data-type-when-using-native-sql-query)

Comment: Edited to use StandardBasicTypes.LONG instead of Hibernate.LONG, since the Hibernate "constant" was previously deprecated and now completely removed from the code. Another option would be to use LongType.INSTANCE.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate gets BigInteger from the DB metadata. You can override by:

`query.addScalar("nextval", LongType.INSTANCE)`

Comment: That would make it return Integers, not Longs. I think you meant LongType.INSTANCE.